# Connect from a docker container to a mysql database in another container

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, mariadb

I would like to access mariadb in the db container from the app container with the following folder configuration, but it does not work with an error.

### directory structure

```
.
├── app
│   └── Dockerfile
├── db
│   └── Dockerfile
└── docker-compose.yml
```

### Code

app/Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:buster

RUN set -x \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests -y \
        mariadb-client \
        vim

CMD [ "tail", "-f" ]
```

db/Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:buster

RUN set -x \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests -y \
        mariadb-server \
        mariadb-client \
        vim

CMD service mysql start \
    && tail -f /dev/null
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  app:
    build: ./app
    networks:
      - frontend

  db:
    build: ./db
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    expose:
      - 3306
    networks:
      - frontend

networks:
  frontend:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  db_data: {}
```

### Execution Commands

I entered the app container and executed the following commands, but I get an error.

```sh
root@0e0ad0889639:/# mysql -h db -uroot
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' (115)

root@0e0ad0889639:/# ping db
PING db (192.168.128.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from test_db_1.test_frontend (192.168.128.3): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.104 ms
64 bytes from test_db_1.test_frontend (192.168.128.3): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.142 ms
```

How can I connect?

### Environment

```sh
❯ docker -v        
Docker version 20.10.12, build e91ed57

❯ docker-compose -v               
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c

❯ sw_vers
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 12.3
BuildVersion:   21E230
```

Comment: Might be a problem with the docker network not allowing connections. A useful test is to try and use the `telnet` program from the app container to connect to port 3306 on the database container: `telnet db 3306`. If the command exits with an error, you'll know there's some problem with the network.

Comment: Are you able to connect (`mysql -uroot`) while in the `app` container?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.15' (115)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64320136/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-192-168-1-15-115)

Comment: Any particular reason you are not using a preconfigured image which is correctly configured for allowing remote connections? The default installation of mariadb only allows connections from localhost

Answer (score 0):

The following method in db container solved the problem.

1. database setting

```
USE mysql;
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' identified by 'pass' WITH GRANT OPTION ;
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' identified by 'pass' WITH GRANT OPTION ;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES ;
```

2. mysql config file setting

```
echo "bind-address = app" >> etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by comments, the default Debian MariaDB configures a `bind-address` to localhost. This is why the [Docker Library mariadb image](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker/blob/bd9968e3387fa60e0a149cae2c1bb43a53ea1f3e/Dockerfile.template#L122-L125) removes those configuration items.

If all you want is a `vim` installed in your container maybe the following to gain all the benefits of a maintained and tested container image:

db/Dockerfile

```
FROM mariadb:10.6
ENV MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
RUN set -x \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests -y \
        vim; \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

note [small editors](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker/issues/416#issuecomment-1051801915) exist if you are interested.