# When I wanna dockerize, I get: django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")

Tags: django, docker

I am attempting to dockerize a Django project that features a MySQL database and nginx. When I run the `docker-compose up --build` command, I receive the error message `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)").`

Here's my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
  app:
    build: ./app
    env_file:
      - .env
    container_name: app
    restart: always
    expose:
        - 8000
    command: bash -c  "python3 manage.py collectstatic --noinput && python3 manage.py migrate --noinput --fake-initial && \
              gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 veblog.wsgi"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${NAME}
      - MYSQL_USER=${USER_NAME}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_HOST=sqldb
    mem_limit: 1g
    depends_on:
      - sqldb
      # - nginx
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/app:/app
      - type: bind
        source: ./volumes/media
        target: /app/media
      - type: bind
        source:  ./volumes/static
        target:  /app/static
    
  
  nginx:
      build: ./nginx
      container_name: nginx
      restart: always
      ports:
        - 8000:80
  
     
  sqldb:
    image:  mysql:latest
    container_name: sqldb
    restart:  always
    depends_on:
      - nginx
    expose:
      - 3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${NAME}
      - MYSQL_USER=${USER_NAME}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${ROOT_PASSWORD} 
      - MYSQL_INITDB_SKIP_TZINFO=true  
      - MYSQL_INIT_COMMAND=SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0;
    volumes:
      - type:  bind
        source:  ./volumes/dbdata
        target:  /var/lib/mysql
      - /usr/share/zoneinfo:/usr/share/zoneinfo:ro
```

This is my `Dockerfile` in the `app` directory:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYCODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN apt update
RUN apt install gcc python3-dev musl-dev -y
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install mysqlclient
COPY ./requirement.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirement.txt
ADD . /app/
RUN pip install gunicorn
```

Here's the Dockerfile for nginx:

```
FROM nginx:alpine
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
ADD default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

And here's my `default.conf` file:

```
upstream app {
    server app:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
    location /media/ {
        alias /app/media;
    }
    location /static/ {
        alias /app/static;
    }
}
```

This is my `settings.py` file:

```py
'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': config('NAME'),
        'USER': config('USER_NAME'),
        'PASSWORD': config('PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': 'localhost',  # host.docker.internal
        'PORT': '3306',
```

MySQL and Apache2 are started and active. I can connect to my database in the terminal. When I set `HOST` to `127.0.0.1`, I get the following error: `(2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (115)").` When I set `HOST` to `sqldb`, I get the following error: `(2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'sqldb' (115)").` `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` and `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` are empty. I have tried the following commands: `sudo chmod -R 755 /var/run/mysqld`, `ln -s /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`, SQL uninstall and install, set IP Docker to bind-address. I use command 'docker build' separately instead of `docker-compose up --build`.

I tried the solutions listed in this link: [ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.15' (115)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64320136/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-192-168-1-15-115), but they didn't work. Specifically, I ran the command `mysql --help | grep -A 1 "Default options" Default options are read from the following files in the given order: /etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf`. I then set the `bind-address` to `0.0.0.0` in `/etc/my.cnf`, `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, and `~/.my.cnf`, but when I logged into mysql and ran `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'bind-address'`, I received the error 'Empty set (0.01 sec)'. I also gave access to my firewall. Can anyone guide me on this?

Answer (score 2):

The error message you're encountering indicates that the Django application is unable to connect to the MySQL database. There are a few potential issues that could be causing this problem.

1. Verify MySQL container name:
   In your Django settings, you're using the hostname "sqldb" to connect to the MySQL container. Make sure that the container name defined in your `docker-compose.yml` file matches the name used in the Django settings. In your case, it should be `sqldb`.
2. Check MySQL host configuration:
   In your Django settings, you have set the MySQL host to `'localhost'`. However, when running in Docker containers, `'localhost'` typically refers to the container itself. Instead, you should use the hostname of the MySQL service defined in your `docker-compose.yml` file, which is `'sqldb'`. Update your Django settings as follows:

   ```py
   'HOST': 'sqldb',
   ```
3. Verify MySQL port configuration:
   In your Django settings, you have set the MySQL port to `'3306'`, which is the default MySQL port. However, when using Docker Compose, the services within the same network can communicate with each other using the container names. Therefore, you don't need to expose the MySQL container's port or specify it in the Django settings. Remove the `expose` section for the `sqldb` service in your `docker-compose.yml` file:

   ```yaml
   expose:
     - 3306
   ```

   Also, update your Django settings:

   ```py
   'PORT': '',
   ```

   With these changes, Django will be able to connect to the MySQL container using the default MySQL port.
4. Verify MySQL credentials:
   Double-check that the values for `NAME`, `USER_NAME`, `PASSWORD`, and `ROOT_PASSWORD` in your `.env` file match the corresponding environment variables used in the `docker-compose.yml` file and Django settings.

After making these changes, try running `docker-compose up --build` again and see if the issue is resolved.