# Can't connect to mysql server from a specific remote system

Tags: mysql, linux

I have mysql working on a server (lets say `ServerA`) and am trying to access it from another server (lets say `ServerB`).

The mysql connection works perfectly with `localhost` calls from same server.

It also works perfectly if I call it from my local windows system, and yet another online linux server (lets say `ServerC`).

But it does not connect from `ServerB`.

Error that I get is:
`Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xx.xx.xx.xx' (115)`

`xx.xx.xx.xx` being the ip of `ServerB`.

I have given remote access to this ip on the `ServerA` already (I had to give same access to my local system ip and also the `ServerC` ip in order to make them work).

I also did a test that even if I remove the remote access for the `ServerB` still the error message keeps saying:
`Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xx.xx.xx.xx' (115)`

While on the other hand, if I remove access for my local system ip (my internet ip) or for my `ServerC` ip, it immediately gives me the error:
`Host 'xx.xx.xx.xx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server`

**My guess is that, the `ServerB` has some setting which is blocking the request to go out, is that possible?**

The `ServerB` is a simple hosting server with below details:

```
cPanel Version: 110.0 (build 17)
Apache Version: 2.4.58
MySQL Version: 10.2.44-MariaDB-cll-lve
Architecture: x86_64
Operating System: linux
Kernel Version: 5.4.0-1105-gke
```

While the host server that has the mysql db (`ServerA`) is also a simple hosting server with below details:

```
cPanel Version: 110.0 (build 15)
Apache Version: 2.4.58
MySQL Version: 5.7.44-cll-lve
Architecture: x86_64
Operating System: linux
Kernel Version: 2.6.32-954.3.5.lve1.4.93.el6.x86_64
```

Does someone have any idea why mysql connection is blocked from `ServerB` only?

Comment: instead of whitelisting the server IP in the remote access section, you can add % to there. using the % mark you can allow any outside servers to access your database

Comment: Isn't this a security threat? allowing everyone to access the mysql server remotely does not look like a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

The error number 115 indicates that the TCP connection has failed.

You need to configure MySQL on ServerA to accept external TCP connections (i.e. to bind to the external TCP IP address and port), see details in the answers to [ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.15' (115)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64320136/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-192-168-1-15-115) .

To debug this further, run `telnet xx.xx.xx.xx 3306 </dev/null` first on ServerA, then on ServerB. If both work (i.e. they display *Connected to*), then your issue is solved. If it works on ServerA only, then it may be a firewall issue from ServerB to ServerA. To debug the firewall issue further, turn off (temporarily) the firewall on ServerA, and if that doesn't help, contact the support of service provider of ServerA.

If connecting (with the MySQL client tool) to ServerA already works from ServerC and your Windows PC, but not from ServerB, then it can be a firewall issue on ServerB (e.g. blocking outgoing connetions on TCP port 3306). Try changing this on the cPanel of ServerB. (I don't know how; look up the docs, ask ServerB support, or ask a separate question on StackOverflow.) Or contact the support of service provider of ServerB. To debug this, run `telnet xx.xx.xx.xx 3306 </dev/null` (MySQL port) on ServerB, and also run `telnet xx.xx.xx.xx 22 </dev/null` (SSH port) on ServerB. If SSH connects (with the *Connected to* message), but MySQL doesn't, then it's indeed a firewall issue.

Comment: The `ServerA` is able to accept external connections, it accepts from my windows pc as well as an online server (`ServerC`). It could be a firewall issue but I guess not on the `ServerA` and instead it could be some issue from `ServerB` that could be blocking an outgoing call, is that possible? How can I check that if I have cpanel access? thanks for the response though.

Comment: If connecting (with the MySQL client tool) to ServerA works from ServerC and your Windows PC, you should add this to the question. This is very relevant info.

Comment: I've added another paragraph to my answer.

Comment: I already mentioned that in the original question and also mentioned in bold that this can be the reason... thanks for the update to your answer, it does not connect to port 3306 but connects to port 22... is it possible to update the firewall settings from cpanel?

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, I don't know how to change firewall settings in cPanel; look up the docs, ask ServerB support, or ask a separate question on StackOverflow