# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to server on '172.17.0.2' (115)

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I'm creating an API using NestJS, TypeORM and MySQL through Docker, and I can't find my error while connecting the database via Docker:

```
[mile@miles book-api]$ docker run --name mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=12345 -d mysql:latest
3818cc3467f4ffc8be132a9670b097cc316ee75597d996635060b24213d7716b
[mile@miles book-api]$ mysql -u root -h 172.17.0.2 -p12345
mysql: Deprecated program name. It will be removed in a future release, use '/usr/bin/mariadb' instead
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to server on '172.17.0.2' (115)`
```

I'm doing everything in the folder that contains the .env, the ormconfig.json, and the docker-compose.yml.I already have the mysql:latest image also. Does anyone know where the error might be? Thanks in advance!

I already tried all the solutions that the IA gave me, which are:

- Switching to MariaDB (Althrough I shouldn't, since in work they ask me to use MySQL.
- The IP is the right one.
- The password is the right one.
- The container is in ejecution, so that's not the problem.
- I also tried this solution

> In the file /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf (Raspi-os
> 2021-03-04 with MariaDB installed), you should replace the line
> "bind-address = 127.0.0.1" (localhost) by "bind-address = 0.0.0.0"
> (all). After, you should restart your MySQL server : $ sudo service
> mariadb restart
> That cames from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64320136/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-192-168-1-15-115)

Comment: what does this have to do with `nestjs`, `typeorm`, or `docker-compose`?  I see docker and mysql being used.  "The IP is the right one." Usually you'd do this with a forwarded port.

Comment: Using the bridge network IP address only works on some platforms and is not recommended. You should map the database port to a host port using `-p` on `docker run` and connect using localhost and the mapped port.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know exactly what might be going on if you provide additional information such as:

- are you using docker compose?
- Nestjs is contained in a container?

From my point of view I would see the following solutions:

1. When creating the container you are not exposing the port through which the communication will take place, that is, without the port you cannot have access. For this your modified command would be:

   ```bash
   docker run --name mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=12345 -d -p 33060:3306 mysql:latest
   ```

   This will allow you to use port `33060` to access the database, as it will be exposed for use.
2. Now together with the previous step you will have the port available, I know that docker gives you an IP to use, but my recommendation is that you use the IP of your machine to access, instead of using the IP `172.17.0.2` use the IP of your machine that should look something like `192.168.0.10` with this you will avoid several problems.

https://platzi.com/tutoriales/1432-docker-2018/3268-como-crear-un-contenedor-con-docker-mysql-y-persistir-la-informacion/

At the end you would connect to something like `192.168.0.10:33060`.