# How to enable a user in mariadb (or mysql) to access the server from any ip address?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, client, remote-access

We have a working server for a course at, for example:

```
172.185.5.5
```

the server works, I can ssh in and use mysql on the machine. I want to use mysql from a remote machine. Suppose I am somewhere in the class B address. Since I don't have a fixed ip address, I want to enable the user to login from anywhere (it's not that secure, and the machine is only running our class database).

We saw a stack overflow answer and tried:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON me.* TO 'me'@'%' identified by 'secret';
```

The grant works, but when I try to log in, it does not work.

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.185.5.5:3306' (111)
```

I also tried it specifically:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON me.* TO 'me'@'172.11.6.72' identified by 'secret';
```

and mysql:

```
mysql -ume -h172.185.5.5 -p
```

same error.

ufw is showing that port 3306 is allowed for all, so that should be ok.

Comment: Make sure mysqld is configured to accept network connections.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64320136/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-192-168-1-15-115